# Change paper orientation for R plots to landscape

Tags: r, orientation

Basic R plots (`plot(x=..., y=...)`) appear to print to portrait-oriented, letter-sized paper. How can I change this to landscape-oriented?

Comment: You need to realize that it is not `plot` that has those defatuls but rather the screen and file graphics devices:  `?Devices`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can change this when you open the graphic device. For example, for `X11`:

```
X11(width=4,height=3)
```

For `postscript()` and `pdf()` you can change the paper size by specifying the `paper` argument: set it to `"a4r"` and `"USr"` for rotated (landscape).

Other graphic devices have similar mechanisms. See the online help for more details.

Comment: Specifically, the settings are `paper = "a4r"` or `paper = "USr"` for a4 or us rotated (to landscape).

Comment: @joran: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added this to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm slightly confused by your mention of the `X11` function... it seems the answer to my question is to set `pdf(paper="USr")`. Do I need `X11` for anything?

Comment: @eykanal: Probably not. It wasn't clear from the question whether the output was getting displayed on the screen, or whether it was going to a file. If it's the latter, `X11()` is irrelevant to your code.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't even realize printing to screen was an option :)  Thanks!